# Autonomous DFU Nordic

Tags: android, dfu

I'm working on an application connected to a BLE device, and I'm focused on the firmware update of the device (DFU). For that, I'm using the android lib created by Nordic and I'm trying to make it autonomous, so a user doesn't have to browse his files and pick the zip of the firmware update.

However, the DFU always stops at 30%, the app loses the bluetooth connection and I have to finish the update manually with an external app.

Is there anyone that has already made this kind of thing with DFU and can help me?

Here is a link to the lib's github: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library

Here is the code I'm currently using, it's a standard DFU procedure with Nordic lib for Android.

```
val starter = DfuServiceInitiator(deviceMacAddress!!)
            .setDeviceName(deviceName)
            .setKeepBond(true)

    starter.setUnsafeExperimentalButtonlessServiceInSecureDfuEnabled(true)
    starter.setZip(uri)
    val controller = starter.start(context!!, DfuService::class.java)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        DfuServiceInitiator.createDfuNotificationChannel(context!!)
    }
```

Edit: Here are some logs that show what happens on runtime

```
2019-01-08 10:54:35.481 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/DfuListener: onDeviceConnected
2019-01-08 10:54:35.481 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/DfuListener: onDfuProcessStarting
2019-01-08 10:54:36.492 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 8ec90003-f315-4f60-9fb8-838830daea50 enable: true
2019-01-08 10:54:41.741 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=11 device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DE
2019-01-08 10:54:41.741 3394-3592/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=12 device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DE
2019-01-08 10:54:41.743 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2019-01-08 10:54:41.743 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=12
2019-01-08 10:54:41.755 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 23058a49-636d-82ab-d641-badd3648cc9a enable: false
2019-01-08 10:54:41.755 3394-3598/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothManager: getConnectionState()
2019-01-08 10:54:41.755 3394-3598/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
2019-01-08 10:54:41.756 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2019-01-08 10:54:41.757 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/Companion: Charac change error Disconnected from FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DE with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION)
2019-01-08 10:54:41.757 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/BleManager: release()
2019-01-08 10:54:41.758 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap I/Companion: onConnectionStateChanged : RxBleConnectionState{DISCONNECTED}
2019-01-08 10:54:41.758 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/BleManager: release()
2019-01-08 10:54:41.759 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/bleManager: error characteristic change : Disconnected from FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DE with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION)
2019-01-08 10:54:41.761 3394-3598/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2019-01-08 10:54:41.761 3394-3598/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=11
2019-01-08 10:54:41.764 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=12 mScannerId=0
2019-01-08 10:54:41.787 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/ConnectionState: disconnected
2019-01-08 10:54:41.872 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2019-01-08 10:54:43.905 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF, auto: false
2019-01-08 10:54:43.906 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
2019-01-08 10:54:43.906 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=766e5e19-e1f9-48d3-a0a0-9c5eeba2b66a
2019-01-08 10:54:43.910 3394-3592/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=11
2019-01-08 10:54:44.059 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=11 device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF
2019-01-08 10:54:44.060 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF
2019-01-08 10:54:44.746 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF interval=24 latency=0 timeout=400 status=0
2019-01-08 10:54:45.045 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
2019-01-08 10:54:45.135 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF Status=0
2019-01-08 10:54:45.224 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF interval=24 latency=0 timeout=400 status=0
2019-01-08 10:54:45.825 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF interval=24 latency=0 timeout=400 status=0
2019-01-08 10:54:46.149 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF mtu: 517
2019-01-08 10:54:46.244 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF mtu=23 status=0
2019-01-08 10:54:46.246 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 8ec90001-f315-4f60-9fb8-838830daea50 enable: true
2019-01-08 10:54:49.738 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/timezone: time : 1.0
2019-01-08 10:54:49.738 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap I/LocationUpdate: 2.2889202 : 48.8515689
2019-01-08 10:55:09.687 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/timezone: time : 1.0
2019-01-08 10:55:09.687 3394-3394/com.thingsaremoving.enovap I/LocationUpdate: 2.2889202 : 48.8515689
2019-01-08 10:55:16.871 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/DfuImpl: Characteristic write error: 133
2019-01-08 10:55:16.871 3394-3406/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=11 device=FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF
2019-01-08 10:55:16.873 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap E/DfuBaseService: Unable to write Op Code 3 (error 133)
2019-01-08 10:55:16.874 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap W/removing.enova: Accessing hidden method Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;->refresh()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-08 10:55:16.875 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: refresh() - device: FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DF
2019-01-08 10:55:16.876 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2019-01-08 10:55:16.876 3394-3698/com.thingsaremoving.enovap D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=11
```

Comment: Any log output?

Comment: Hi, I added the logs from the connection of the dfu to its interruption. The interruption always happens around 30%

Comment: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library/issues

Comment: I would investigate on that: `Disconnected from FE:E6:FD:B8:13:DE with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION)`. For example set insecureDfu and/or keepBond to false.

Comment: Thanks for the tip jim, I'll check that if I have this problem again. In my case, it happened that the bootloader was inadequate to the device. I changed the device I'm using and the dfu is clean now.